# Why my server skips if statement and goes to else part (try again )?

Tags: java, serversocket

**My server code**

The problem is in the server code when checking the username and password for login it outputs the "try again" message every time

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
//test
public class server {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ServerSocket listener;
        int clientid=0;
        try 
        {
             listener = new ServerSocket(10000,10);

             while(true)
             {
                System.out.println("Main thread listening for incoming new connections");
                Socket newconnection = listener.accept();

                System.out.println("New connection received and spanning a thread");
                Connecthandler t = new Connecthandler(newconnection, clientid);
                clientid++;
                t.start();
             }

        } 

        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Socket not opened");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


class Connecthandler extends Thread
{

    Socket individualconnection;
    int socketid;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    ObjectInputStream in;
    String message;


    public Connecthandler(Socket s, int i)
    {
        individualconnection = s;
        socketid = i;
    }

    void sendMessage(String msg)
    {
        try{
            out.writeObject(msg);
            out.flush();
            System.out.println("client>" + msg);
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {

        int clubId;
        String clubName;
        String clubEmail;
        int fundsAvailTransfer;
        String agentName;
        int agentId;
        String agentEmail;
        String username;
        int password;
        ClubUser loggedInUser = null;
        try 
        {

            out = new ObjectOutputStream(individualconnection.getOutputStream());
            out.flush();
            in = new ObjectInputStream(individualconnection.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("Connection"+ socketid+" from IP address "+individualconnection.getInetAddress());


            //Commence
            do 
            {
                ArrayList<ClubUser> clubuser = new ArrayList<ClubUser>();
                do
                {
                    sendMessage("Please Enter 1 to Register or 2 to Login");
                    message = (String)in.readObject();
                }while(!message.equals("1")&&!message.equals("2"));

                if(message.equals("1"))
                {

                    sendMessage("Enter 1 to Register Club or 2 to Register Player Agent");
                    message = (String)in.readObject();
                    // Club Registration

                    if(message.equals("1"))
                    {
                    sendMessage("Enter Club Name: ");
                    message = (String)in.readObject();
                    clubName = message;

                    sendMessage("Enter Club Id: ");
                    message = (String)in.readObject();
                    clubId = Integer.parseInt(message);

                    sendMessage("Enter Club Email: ");
                    message = (String)in.readObject();
                    clubEmail = message;

                    sendMessage("Enter Funds Available To Transfer: ");
                    message = (String)in.readObject();
                    fundsAvailTransfer = Integer.parseInt(message);

                    ClubUser cu = new ClubUser(clubId, clubName, clubEmail, fundsAvailTransfer);
                    clubuser.add(cu);

                    for (ClubUser u : clubuser)
                    {
                        System.out.println(u);
                    }// for

                    }// innerif


                }// outerif

                else if(message.equals("2"))
                {
                    sendMessage("Please enter Club Name: ");
                    message = (String)in.readObject();
                    username = message;

                    sendMessage("Please enter Club Id: ");
                    message = (String)in.readObject();
                    password = Integer.parseInt(message);

                    for (ClubUser user : clubuser)
                    {
                        if (user.getClubId()==(password))
                        {
                        if (user.getClubName().equalsIgnoreCase(username))
                        {

                                loggedInUser = user;

                                // when a user is found, "break" stops iterating through the list
                               // break;
                            }
                        }
                    }// for
                     if(loggedInUser != null)
                        {
                            sendMessage("welcome!!!!!! " + loggedInUser.getClubName());
                        }
                     // problem here
                        else
                        {
                            sendMessage("try again ");
                        }


                }// else if


                sendMessage("Y to repeat or N to terminate");

                message = (String)in.readObject();
            }while(message.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally
        {
            try 
            {
                out.close();
                in.close();
                individualconnection.close();
            }


            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }

}
```

**My client code**

The client code seems to be ok.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
//test
public class Client 
{

    private Socket connection;
    private String message;
    private  Scanner console;
    private  String ipaddress;
    private  int portaddress;
    private ObjectOutputStream out;
    private ObjectInputStream in;

    public Client()
    {
        console = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the IP Address of the server");
        ipaddress = console.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the TCP Port");
        portaddress  = console.nextInt();

    }

    void sendMessage(String msg)
    {
        try{
            out.writeObject(msg);
            out.flush();
            System.out.println("client>" + msg);
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
            Client temp = new Client();
            temp.clientapp();
    }

    public void clientapp()
    {

        try 
        {
            connection = new Socket(ipaddress,portaddress);

            out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            out.flush();
            in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("Client Side ready to communicate");


            /// Client App.

            do
            {
                do
                {
                    message = (String)in.readObject();
                    System.out.println(message);
                    message = console.next();
                    sendMessage(message);
                }while(!message.equalsIgnoreCase("1")&&!message.equalsIgnoreCase("2"));

                if(message.equals("1"))
                {
                    // reg as club or agent
                    message = (String)in.readObject();
                    System.out.println(message);
                    message = console.next();
                    sendMessage(message);

                    if(message.equals("1"))
                    {
                        // club name
                        message = (String)in.readObject();
                        System.out.println(message);
                        message = console.next();
                        sendMessage(message);
                        // club id
                        message = (String)in.readObject();
                        System.out.println(message);
                        message = console.next();
                        sendMessage(message);
                        // club email
                        message = (String)in.readObject();
                        System.out.println(message);
                        message = console.next();
                        sendMessage(message);
                        // club funds
                        message = (String)in.readObject();
                        System.out.println(message);
                        message = console.next();
                        sendMessage(message);
                    }// inner if

                }// outer if

                else if(message.equals("2"))
                {
                    // club name
                    message = (String)in.readObject();
                    System.out.println(message);
                    message = console.next();
                    sendMessage(message);
                    // club id
                    message = (String)in.readObject();
                    System.out.println(message);
                    message = console.next();
                    sendMessage(message);

                    // welcome message
                    message = (String)in.readObject();
                    System.out.println(message);


                }// outer else if

                message = (String)in.readObject();
                System.out.println(message);
                message = console.next();
                sendMessage(message);

            }while(message.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

            out.close();
            in.close();
            connection.close();
        } 

        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}


my clubuser class with getters and setters



public class ClubUser extends server{
    int clubId;
    String clubName;
    String clubEmail;
    int fundsAvailTransfer;

    public ClubUser(int clubId, String clubName, String clubEmail, int fundsAvailTransfer) {
        super();
        this.clubId = clubId;
        this.clubName = clubName;
        this.clubEmail = clubEmail;
        this.fundsAvailTransfer = fundsAvailTransfer;
    }

    int getClubId() {
        return clubId;
    }

    private void setClubId(int clubId) {
        this.clubId = clubId;
    }

    String getClubName() {
        return clubName;
    }

    private void setClubName(String clubName) {
        this.clubName = clubName;
    }

    private String getClubEmail() {
        return clubEmail;
    }

    private void setClubEmail(String clubEmail) {
        this.clubEmail = clubEmail;
    }

    private int getFundsAvailTransfer() {
        return fundsAvailTransfer;
    }

    private void setFundsAvailTransfer(int fundsAvailTransfer) {
        this.fundsAvailTransfer = fundsAvailTransfer;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClubUser clubId=" + clubId + ", clubName=" + clubName + ", clubEmail=" + clubEmail
                + ", fundsAvailTransfer=" + fundsAvailTransfer;
    }


}
```

Another thing I want is to save the added user details in a file and then initialize the array with them at the start of program.  How do I do that?

Comment: `while(!message.equals("1") || !message.equals("2"));`

Answer (score -2):

In the Connecthandler::run() method, try moving the ArrayList "clubUser" outside of the scope of the outermost do/while. This way it won't be re-initialized for every iteration.

```
// Place the list initialization here; outside the scope of the outer-most do loop
ArrayList<ClubUser> clubuser = new ArrayList<ClubUser>();
do {
    // remove from here.
    // ArrayList<ClubUser> clubuser = new ArrayList<ClubUser>(); 
    do {
        sendMessage("Please Enter 1 to Register or 2 to Login");
        message = (String) in.readObject();
    } while (!message.equals("1") && !message.equals("2"));

    ...
}
```

Comment: You should provide more information to clarify your question. Please check the following guide to know how to make a proper question on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: if i type wrong password then the sentinel loop works and again asks for register or login and after inputting 2 client stucks and server shows java eof error

Comment: java.io.EOFException
 at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:3062)
 at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1561)
 at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
 at Connecthandler.run(server.java:192)